# Using filter in listview adapter inflate

Tags: android, listview, inflate, baseadapter, textwatcher

I'm having problem I can not do a search on my listview!

I tried to implement listview with inflate and do a search, but unfortunately I could not ... There appears no error in the logcat and tried to debug but unfortunately apparently it's alright ... Simply write when not in textview in listview filtar begins ...

Below is my code

FriendRequestListener.class

```
/*
 * callback after friends are fetched via me/friends.
 * 
 */
public class FriendsRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        dialog.dismiss();

        try{
            arrayName = new ArrayList<String>();
            jsonArray = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(json_data.has("name")){
                    String getFriendName = json_data.getString("name");

                    arrayName.add(getFriendName);
                }else{
                    String getFriendName = null;
                    arrayName.add(getFriendName);
                }
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        stringName = new String[arrayName.size()];
        stringName = arrayName.toArray(stringName);

        EscolhaAmigosFacebook.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter = new FriendListAdapter(EscolhaAmigosFacebook.this, stringName, arrayName);
            friendsListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            friendsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        });
    }
```

FriendApapter.class

```
/**
 * Definition of the list adapter
 */
public class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    String[] fetFriendName;

    List<String> arrayList;
    List<String> mOriginalValues;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
    EscolhaAmigosFacebook friendsList;

    FriendListAdapter(EscolhaAmigosFacebook friendsList, String[] stringName, ArrayList<String> arrayName) {
        this.friendsList = friendsList;
        if (Utility.model == null) {
            Utility.model = new FriendsGetProfilePics();
        }
        Utility.model.setListener(this);

        fetFriendName = stringName;

        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mOriginalValues = arrayName;

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(friendsList.getBaseContext());

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mOriginalValues.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mOriginalValues.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;

        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (vi == null) {

            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

            TextView txtFriendsName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            txtFriendsName.setText(fetFriendName[position]);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        try {
                 holder.profile_pic.setImageBitmap(Utility.model.getImage(
                 jsonObject.getString("id"), jsonObject.getString("picture")));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                holder.name.setText("");
            }   
        return vi;
       }



    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter(){

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                arrayList = (List<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                List<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;
                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString();

                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                        String data = mOriginalValues.get(i);

                        if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))   {
                            FilteredArrList.add(data);
                        }
                    }

                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                }

                return results;
            }

        };
        return filter;
    }

}
```

Method onComplete

```
     et_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Search);
    et_search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

I know it looked great, but if anyone has the patience to help me, please!
I've tried looking at various posts but got nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Filter yet on an adapter, but I've used adapter a lot and from what I can tell after filtering you put the results on the arraylist, but you don't use arrayList on the getCount, getItem, getView, so the filter you created on the data is not used, but the full list of items.